# How to convert UNIX timestamp into date without the time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, unix-timestamp

I have a table full of UNIX timestamps and I want to strip the time and check againt the CURRENT_DATE and grab the total count.

```
$shippedCount = Model::whereRaw('DATE(UNIX TABLE) = CURRENT_DATE')->count();
```

What is the best way to go about this.

Comment: `date(from_unixtimestamp(yourfield))`

Comment: @MarcB Hey thanks man.  I got it to work but now I want to compare it to the CURRENT_DAY - 1 , -2 , -3  etc...How can I compare to the current day?

Comment: then `date(from_unixtimestamp(yourfield) - interval 1 day)`

Comment: Thanks so much man...you're a lifesaver